# Why am I getting IOException and SocketException while writing to NetworkStream?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, socket.io, ioexception, system.net.sockets

I have a dll which connects me to a software, let's call it driver1.
I have a java program which has to connect to driver1 and query its status.
The dll provides me functions for connecting and querying the status.

I wrote a c++ program which I gave the dll as a reference and I am able to use the dll from it. I can connect to driver1 and query its status.
Then I created a TcpListener that my Java program can connect as a client.
I simply accept the client in c++ and wait for recieving data from Java program.

I send the data from Java side (for example a command representing "connect" method of dll).
The command is well recieved from the c++ side and it parses and calls the specified function of dll. However when I want to write the return value of the dll function to the NetworkStream to send the return value to Java side I get an exception saying:

> System.IO.IOException: IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection. An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.

The c++ side code is the similar to the TcpListener sample from the msdn site:

```
#using <System.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Net;
using namespace System::Net::Sockets;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Threading;
void main()
{
    try
    {

        // Set the TcpListener on port 1124.
        Int32 port = 1124;
        IPAddress^ localAddr = IPAddress::Parse( "127.0.0.1" );

        // TcpListener* server = new TcpListener(port);
        TcpListener^ server = gcnew TcpListener( localAddr,port );

        // Start listening for client requests.
        server->Start();

        // Buffer for reading data
        array<Byte>^bytes = gcnew array<Byte>(256);
        String^ data = nullptr;

        Console::Write( "Waiting for a connection... " );

        // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
        TcpClient^ client = server->AcceptTcpClient();
        Console::WriteLine( "Connected!" );
        data = nullptr;

        while(true) 
        {
            // Get a stream Object* for reading and writing
            NetworkStream^ stream = client->GetStream();
            Int32 i;

            // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
            while ( i = stream->Read( bytes, 0, bytes->Length ) )
            {

                // Translate data bytes to a ASCII String*.
                data = Text::Encoding::ASCII->GetString( bytes, 0, i );
                Console::WriteLine( "Received: {0}", data );

                // Process the data sent by the client.
                /*
                 *
                 * Here I parse the data, understand what method of the dll to call.
                 * Call it and make a String^ from the return value.
                 *
                 *
                 */
                array<Byte>^msg = Text::Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes( returnValue );

                // Send back a response.
                stream->Write( msg, 0, msg->Length );
                Console::WriteLine( "Sent: {0}", data );
            }
        }

        // Shutdown and end connection
        client->Close();
     }
     catch ( SocketException^ e ) 
     {
         Console::WriteLine( "SocketException: {0}", e );
     }

     Console::WriteLine( "\nHit enter to continue..." );
     Console::Read();
}
```

I get the exception on the line where I call:

> stream->Write()

Any ideas about what is happenning?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: what does the java code look like after its stream.Write? does it close the socket?

Comment: @Default, No it does not close the socket, I can both recieve and send to/from Java side before I connect to the dll.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the connection is terminating for some reason.  I think if you check the status of the connection using the DOS command `NETSTAT -A` you will find the connection is either closed or in a pending state.  It is difficult to say which end of the connection (client or server) created the problem.

Also, try debugging the `TCPSocket` to check it's state just before sending your data.  It could be one end is closing the connection prematurely....

Comment: Thanks @justderb, I have checked the connections with `netstat -a` and saw that after the c++ side recieves "connect" command from java and connects the dll the old connection of `127.0.0.1:1124` is dead and the new connection between c++ side and dll `127.0.0.1:7600` is opened. When I checked the client socket in debug mode just after dll connection I see that "Available" property shows SocketException. Before it was 0.

Comment: by the way before I call the connect function of the dll, I can write to the stream anything and send it to client.

Comment: Well I don't know what you dll is or what it is doing so you will need to figure that out on your own.  But, I am glad you have found the problem!

Comment: thanks. I also don't know what is inside dll :) Ok I will try to use the dll from java directly...